# how to get scrapy go to the next page?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm triyng to build scraper with Scapy.
I don't undestand why Scrapy doesn't want to go to the next page. I thouht to extract link from pagination area..but, alas.
My rule for extracting urls for going to the next page

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='/html/body/div[19]/div[5]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[3]/ul',allow=('page=[0-9]*')), follow=True)
```

Crawler

```
Class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "arbal"
    allowed_domains = ["bigbasket.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://bigbasket.com/pc/bread-dairy-eggs/bread-bakery/?nc=cs"
    ]

    rules = (
             Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='/html/body/div[19]/div[4]/ul',allow=('pc\/.*.\?nc=cs')), follow=True),
             Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='/html/body/div[19]/div[5]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[3]/ul',allow=('page=[0-9]*')), follow=True),
             Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//*[@id="products-container"]',allow=('pd\/*.+')), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
             )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = AlabaItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item['brand_name'] = hxs.select('.//*[contains(@id, "slidingProduct")]/div[2]/div[1]/a/text()').extract()
        item['prod_name'] =  hxs.select('//*[contains(@id, "slidingProduct")]/div[2]/div[2]/h1/text()').extract()
        yield item
```

Comment: it seems crawl doesn't want to go to the next url beacause getting relative url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an AJAX-style pagination which is not easy to follow, but doable.

Using browser developer tools you may see that every time you switch pages, there is an XHR request being sent to `http://bigbasket.com/product/facet/get-page/` with `sid` and `page` parameters:

[image]

The problem is that `sid` parameter - this is what we'll extract from the first link containing `sid` on the page.

The response is in JSON format containing `products` key which is basically an HTML code of the `products_container` block on a page.

Note that `CrawlSpider` would not help in this case. We need to use a regular spider and follow the pagination "manually".

Another question you may have: how would we know how many pages to follow - the idea here would be to extract the total number of products on the page from the "Showing X - Y of Z products" label in the bottom of the page, then divide the total number of products by 20 (20 products per page).

Implementation:

```
import json
import urllib

import scrapy


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "arbal"
    allowed_domains = ["bigbasket.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://bigbasket.com/pc/bread-dairy-eggs/bread-bakery/?nc=cs"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # follow pagination
        num_pages = int(response.xpath('//div[@class="noItems"]/span[@class="bFont"][last()]/text()').re(r'(\d+)')[0])
        sid = response.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "sid")]/@href').re(r'sid=(\w+)(?!&|\z)')[0]

        base_url = 'http://bigbasket.com/product/facet/get-page/?'
        for page in range(1, num_pages/20 + 1):
            yield scrapy.Request(base_url + urllib.urlencode({'sid': sid, 'page': str(page)}), dont_filter=True, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body)

        selector = scrapy.Selector(text=data['products'])
        for product in selector.xpath('//li[starts-with(@id, "product")]'):
            title = product.xpath('.//div[@class="muiv2-product-container"]//img/@title').extract()[0]
            print title
```

For the page set in `start_urls` it prints 281 product titles.

Comment: Ok.This is good way.But if I print value of this: ` Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='/html/body/div[19]/div[5]/div[2]/div[5]/div[3]/ul',allow=('pc\/.*.\?nc=cs#!page=[0-9]*'),process_value=my_process_value), follow=True) ` I get true urls, scrapy doesnt open them

Comment: @AleksanderGordienko yeah, this is what I'm trying to say - it is an AJAX-based pagination and you have to deal with it the way I've suggested..понимаешь, Сань? :)

Comment: I tried to run your example, but I got the next error: 
            title = product.xpath('.//div[@class="muiv2-product-container"]//img
/@title').extract()[0]
        exceptions.IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @AleksanderGordienko watch the extra space inside the xpath. Should be `.//div[@class="muiv2-product-container"]//img/@title`.